# How do I plot both median and mean of a dataframe slice using pandas plot function on jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to visualize data from a pandas dataframe I recently created.

In order to do that, I'm using the pandas plot function which uses matplotlib.
I want to plot the median and mean side by side in order to compare them for each level of height.
This is what I've come up with so far. This already gives me the mean with standard deviation
passed as `yerr` argument

```py
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


data_to_plot = "Temperature"
influence = "Height"

df_mean = df.loc[df["Type"]=="Type1",[data_to_plot, influence]].groupby(influence).mean()
df_median = df.loc[df["Type"]=="Type1",[data_to_plot, influence]].groupby(influence).median()
df_std = df.loc[df["Type"]=="Type1",[data_to_plot, influence]].groupby(influence).std()

ax1 = df_mean.plot(kind='bar',
                   legend=True,
                   yerr=df_std,
                   title=f"Type 1: {data_to_plot} as a function of {influence}")

for i, v in enumerate(pd.Series(df_mean[data_to_plot])):
    ax1.text(i, v+2, "%.2f" %v, ha="center", c="blue")
plt.ylim(-10, 150)
plt.show()
```

The following code gives me a plot with mean values of Temperature for each specific and discrete heights, with the mean value written over each graph box.

I would like for the median to appear in the same way as the mean, while retaining the written values and the deviation for the mean columns.

I was able to use the `dataframe.describe()` function of pandas which gives me too much info and doesn't retain the numeric values added to the graph.

Comment: This question is not reproducible without **data**. This question needs a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). Please see [How to provide a reproducible dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52413246/7758804), then **[edit] your question**, and paste the clipboard into a code block. Always provide a [mre] **with code, data, errors, current output, and expected output, as [formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)**. If relevant, plot images are okay. If you don't include an mre, it is likely the question will be downvoted, closed, and deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your code is correct you can use the same approach that you used to plot your mean values.

The `pandas.Dataframe.plot()` method is a convenience function is called matplotlib under the hood and it returns a `matplotlib.axes` object. This means you can do anything you can normally do with a `matplotlib.axes` like `ax.plot([my_values_to_plot])`. If you're happy with your current approach you can pass your object `ax1` back to `pandas.DataFrame.plot()` to update your ax1 object.

```
ax1 = df_mean.plot(kind='bar',
                   legend=True,
                   yerr=df_std,
                   title=f"Type 1: {data_to_plot} as a function of {influence}")

ax1 = df_median.plot(kind='bar',
                   legend=True,
                   yerr=df_std,
                   title=f"Type 1: {data_to_plot} as a function of {influence}",
ax=ax1)
```

NB `df_median` and `ax=ax1`